# Case Auto Creation to disable from Noreply@saleforce

Tags: workflow, filters

I've created a workflow with field on Case Object.

```
Case:WebEmail not equal to noreply@salesforce.com
```

but yet I'm still receiving cases created although the filter is set to eliminate the cases created from noreply@salesforce.com.

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Its difficult for anyone to advise you without seeing your workflow rule.

Comment: I'm unable enclose screenshot for Workflow, unless you are requesting for a complete line by line sentence for the workflow.

Comment: Make sure, the email field is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

Case:WebEmail **Not equals To** noreply@salesforce.com

To

Case:WebEmail **Not CONTAINS** noreply@salesforce.com